# How to fix data range filter in table?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using a script to filter dates between start/end dates but it won't do anything in my table.

```
            <script>
                $(document).ready(function () {

                    $(function () {
                        var start = moment("2019-10-01 00:00:00");
                        var end = moment("2019-10-31 23:59:59");

                        function cb(start, end) {
                            $('#reportrange span').html(start.format('MMMM D, YYYY') + ' - ' + end.format('MMMM D, YYYY'));
                        }

                        $('#reportrange').daterangepicker({
                            startDate: start,
                            endDate: end,
                            ranges: {

                            }
                        }, cb);

                        cb(start, end);

                    });


                    $('#reportrange').on('apply.daterangepicker', function (ev, picker) {
                        var start = picker.startDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
                        var end = picker.endDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD');


                        console.log("-----------------------------");

                        $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
                            function (settings, data, dataIndex) {
                                var min = new Date(start);
                                var max = new Date(end);
                                var startDate = new Date(data[1]);
                                console.log(startDate + " <= " + max + " --- " + (startDate <= max));

                                if (min == null && max == null) {
                                    return true;
                                }
                                if (min == null && startDate <= max) {
                                    return true;
                                }
                                if (max == null && startDate >= min) {
                                    return true;
                                }
                                if (startDate <= max && startDate >= min) {
                                    return true;
                                }
                                return false;
                            }
                        );
                        table.draw();
                        $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.pop();
                    });

                });

            </script>
```

And this is the table, I expect it to filter the dates with start & end date but it doesn't do anything at all

```
                <div class="card-body">
                                <div id="tablas">
                                    <div id="var receive">
                                        <div class="table-striped">
                                            <table class="table table-bordered" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
                                                <thead align="center">
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <th>A</th>
                                                        <th>B</th>
                                                        <th>C</th>
                                                        <th>D</th>
                                                        <th>E</th>
                                                        <th>Date</th>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </thead>
                                                <tbody id="mydataTable">
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td align="center">1</td>
                                                        <td>987654 UserName</td>
                                                        <td align="center">Coins</td>
                                                        <td align="right">$1,000.00</td>
                                                        <td align="center">07/16/19</td>
                                                        <td align="center">
                                                            <form action="~/Index"> <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Select</button></form>
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>


                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td align="center">2</td>
                                                        <td>123456 UserName</td>
                                                        <td align="center">Coins</td>
                                                        <td align="right">$1,000.00</td>
                                                        <td align="center">10/16/19</td>
                                                        <td align="center">
                                                            <form action="~/Index"> <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Select</button></form>
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>




                                                </tbody>
                                            </table>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

I took this example from this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ankepv5v/70/) looking up online for answers, since my table is renderized on the go and there's no sql connection well all the examples online won't help me doing this :(

Reportrange goes just above the table it's a buttom

```
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 form-group">
                <label>Buscar por fecha:</label>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <div id="reportrange" class="btn btn-info btn-lg">
                        <span class="input-group-append">
                        </span> <b class="caret"></b>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Your script refers to the Id `reportrange` which is nowhere to be found in your HTML.

Comment: sry bro just added it, it's the buttom that actually pops up the data range window

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:**

Now this actually *is* an answer to your question: I rebuilt your logic after looking at the https://www.daterangepicker.com/ and moment.js documentation.

The filtering of rows can be done in the callback function to the daterangepicker as shown below. A table row is displayed only if its date lies between the chosen start and end dates of the daterangepicker. If you actually want to see the chosen range after you picked it you should also make the daterangepicker field an `<input type="text">` field.

```js
$('#reportrange').daterangepicker({startOfWeek: 'monday'},function(start,end){
  $('#mydataTable tr').each((i,tr)=>{                 // go through each tr of table body:
   var dt=moment($('td:eq(4)',tr).text(),'MM/DD/YY'); // parse the date in column 5 using moment.js
   $(tr).toggle( start<dt && dt<end );                // if dt is between start and end then show, else hide
  })
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/latest/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/latest/moment.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css" />

<input type="text" id="reportrange">
<div class="card-body">
 <div id="tablas">
  <div id="var receive">
   <div class="table-striped">
    <table class="table table-bordered" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
     <thead align="center">
      <tr><th>A</th><th>B</th><th>C</th><th>D</th><th>E</th><th>Date</th></tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody id="mydataTable">
      <tr>
       <td align="center">1</td>
       <td>987654 UserName</td>
       <td align="center">Coins</td>
       <td align="right">$1,000.00</td>
       <td align="center">07/16/19</td>
       <td align="center">
           <form action="~/Index"> <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Select</button></form>
       </td>
      </tr><tr>
       <td align="center">2</td>
       <td>123456 UserName</td>
       <td align="center">Coins</td>
       <td align="right">$1,000.00</td>
       <td align="center">10/16/19</td>
       <td align="center">
           <form action="~/Index"> <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Select</button></form>
       </td>
      </tr><tr>
       <td align="center">3</td>
       <td>007 somebody else</td>
       <td align="center">Coins</td>
       <td align="right">$100.00</td>
       <td align="center">10/20/19</td>
       <td align="center">
           <form action="~/Index"> <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Select</button></form>
       </td>
      </tr><tr>
       <td align="center">4</td>
       <td>789101 UserName</td>
       <td align="center">Coins</td>
       <td align="right">$3,210.00</td>
       <td align="center">11/07/19</td>
       <td align="center">
           <form action="~/Index"> <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Select</button></form>
       </td>
      </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry for the incognito code, added some values to the table, noticed that the E column was actually the last one and the date value on the <td> was one step before last <td> anyways, hope it makes more sense now :)

Comment: A little to late but thanks @cars10m this helped me out to understand something I just required to do today and now I was able to do it because of you

Answer (score 0):

The code below uses jQuery and illustrates sorting, and two ways of filtering based on the value of and input field with id order_index that is in a table row. The three parts are separate, and do not rely on each other to work. You will need to tweak it a bit to fit your case.

What is important in your case is to get the date into a javascript Date class. Unfortunately the parsing built into javascript is not reliable since it is considered implementation dependent so you'll have to fit it to your particular case. I suggest checking **'javascript string to date'** search mask in google. That should get you started. Once you get your date in the proper format( Date ) you can compare it like any other variable.

```
    var l_rows = [];
    f_table.find('tr').each(function(){
        var l_currRow  = $(this);
        l_rows.push(l_currRow);
    })

    //filtering 1, the result from the filtering is irrelevant
    //for scope of the question, but in the general case
    //it is what you are after
    //in here since you want to manage a table
    //you can go without the filtering of the array
    var l_filteredRows = l_rows.filter(function(f_row){
        var l_key = f_row.find('#order_index').val();
        var l_bResult = (/* condition here*/);
        if(l_bResult){
            f_row.show();
        }else{
            f_row.hide();
        }
        return l_bResult;
    });

    //filtering 2. no filter to the array, just iteration
    f_table.find('tr').each(function(){
        var l_key = $(this).find('#order_index ').val();
        var l_bResult = (/*condition here*/);
        if(l_bResult){
            f_row.show();
        }else{
            f_row.hide();
        }
        return l_bResult;
    });     


    //sorting
    l_rows.sort(function (a, b) {
        var keyA = parseInt($('td', a).find('#order_index').val());
        var keyB = parseInt($('td', b).find('#order_index').val());
        if(keyA > keyB) return 1;
        if(keyA < keyB) return -1;

        return 0; 
    });
    f_table.html('');
    for(var i=0;i<l_rows.length;i++){
        f_table.append(l_rows[i]);
    }
```

Comment: I haven't been able to use this, I even feel ashamed to share what I've tried, let me keep playing with this until I find a way to use it, altho so far I haven't been able to do so

Comment: The code looks good for sorting according to date. But, didn't OP mention he wants to filter?

Comment: I think filtering is similar enough

Comment: on a second thought filtering comes with some specifics.I will edit the code later today